# What could be the cause for "jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code that I am trying you place in my articles:

http://jsbin.com/dorimamaji/edit?html,console,output

The purpose of this is to offer collapsible paragraphs (DIVs) using `localStorage`  to remember the previous state (e.g. when the reader leaves the page and then returns). Please see the above jsbin link for an example.

At this point if I use the jsbin code it works fine. The problem appears when I place the code in Joomla it does not work anymore. The `toggleDiv` function is OK but the `localStorage` does not seem to work. I think that it has something to do with the **document.ready** function but I am not sure. What else can I use?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".collapsible").each(function(index) {
    if (typeof($(this).attr('id'))!="undefined") {
      id=$(this).attr('id')
      var state = localStorage.getItem(id)
      ele = document.getElementById(id)
      if (state=="true") {
        ele.style.display = 'block' 
      } else {
        ele.style.display = 'none' 
      }                          
    }
  })
});

window.toggleDiv = function(divId) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(divId);
  var state=$(ele).is(':visible');
  $(ele).toggle();
  state=$(ele).is(':visible');
  localStorage.setItem( divId, state);  
}
</script>

<style>
a:hover {
  color: purple;
}
a:active {
  color: purple;
}
</style>

<a class="ConceptLevel1" href="javascript:toggleDiv('PktS/h+L5EeSqM/4hMH9JA11');" 

style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold; font-size:13pt">Collapsible divs</a><br>
  <div class="collapsible" style="padding-left:15px; " id="PktS/h+L5EeSqM/4hMH9JA11">
      <div>fds</div>
      <div>sdfdsfdfdsf</div>
      <div>sdfsdf</div>
      <div>gdhgf</div>
    <a class="ConceptLevel2" href="javascript:toggleDiv('SPrQVTbDx0WO6As2F+43tw11');" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt">hfghg</a><br>
    <div class="collapsible" style="padding-left:15px; " id="SPrQVTbDx0WO6As2F+43tw11">
      <div>hfghgh</div>
      <div>fghfgh</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note: Joomla is already configured not to strip out code inserted into article

**Update**:

This seems to be a JQuery problem.
For some reasons this line

```
$('.collapsible').each(function(index)
```

returns this error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'each' of null
```

This happens only when the code is inserted in an article. It seems to me that the selector `$('.collapsible')` returns nothing, hence the result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even if jQuery couldn't find `.collapsible`, it would return an empty collection and would have the `each` method.

My **guess** (specially because it only happens in Joomla) is that some other script is taking the `$` var. So, things could be happening in this order:

1. jQuery loads
2. your code runs, `$` is jQuery, so `$(document).ready` works, but the callback is not executed yet
3. another script is loaded and assigned to `$`
4. now the document is ready, the callback will be executed, and `$` is not jQuery anymore

Simplest way to know if that is the case is to replace all `$` in your code with `jQuery`. Example:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".collapsible").each(function(index) { ...
```

You can also use [encapsulation](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/):

```
(function($){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // ...your code...
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: The encapsulation seems to fix the problem for the first function but now the toggle function is giving me an error 101-t2:325 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).is is not a function on the onli line that is using $ in the toggle function. How do I encapsulate that ?

Comment: I used JQuery before instead of jQuery.... :-( I wasted so much time. It is working now. Thnaks a lot!